# MAX and MIN add in query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.price, b.price, a.delivery_hour, a.resource_id, b.delivery_date
             FROM mms_realtime_dispatch_prices_report AS a
             INNER JOIN mms_realtime_expost_prices_report AS b 
             ON a.resource_id = b.resource_id
             AND a.delivery_hour = b.delivery_hour
             AND a.delivery_date = b.delivery_date
             WHERE a.delivery_date = '2013-09-21'
             ORDER BY a.resource_id ASC
```

This is my query. Is it possible to add a new column that determine the max and the min in price?

Comment: Min and max based on what? That involves grouping - but based on what? Also, is it SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: base on delivery hour sir in mysql

Comment: SELECT max(a.price), min(b.price) _<rest of ur query>_ .. group by a.delivery_hour,a.resource_id,b.deliverydate

Comment: Szymon is right max and min based on what?

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT MIN(a.price) as MIN_PRICE, MAX(a.price) as MAX_PRICE, b.price, a.delivery_hour, a.resource_id, b.delivery_date
         FROM mms_realtime_dispatch_prices_report AS a
         INNER JOIN mms_realtime_expost_prices_report AS b 
         ON a.resource_id = b.resource_id
         AND a.delivery_hour = b.delivery_hour
         AND a.delivery_date = b.delivery_date
         WHERE a.delivery_date = '2013-09-21'
         GROUP BY b.price, a.delivery_hour, a.resource_id, b.delivery_date
         ORDER BY a.resource_id ASC
```

Comment: If it works for you, you can mark it as answer, by clicking the tick on the left side of the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT max(a.price), min(b.price), a.delivery_hour, a.resource_id, b.delivery_date
         FROM mms_realtime_dispatch_prices_report AS a
         INNER JOIN mms_realtime_expost_prices_report AS b 
         ON a.resource_id = b.resource_id
         AND a.delivery_hour = b.delivery_hour
         AND a.delivery_date = b.delivery_date
         WHERE a.delivery_date = '2013-09-21'
         GROUP BY a.delivery_hour, a.resource_id, b.delivery_date
         ORDER BY a.resource_id ASC
```

Comment: Isn't it the same as the previous answer?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK nope, check the `group by` condition.

Comment: That's because you messed up with the prices, there are 2 prices retrieved and you selected Min for 1 and Max for the other

Comment: @Nadeem_MK yeah, the question is not clear. I think he want it like this.